# About p-laplacian and variations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, p-laplace

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^{n}}$ be a domain (open and connected set), for $p\geq 2$, the $p$-laplacian is defined by:

$\Delta_p u= \operatorname{div} (|\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u)$, in non-divergence form the $p$-laplacian is

$\Delta_p u = |\nabla u|^{p-2}tr \{ (I+(p-2)\frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|}\otimes \frac{\nabla u} {|\nabla u|})D^2u \}$

Associated this equation, there exists a function $F: \mathbb{R}^{n} \times S \to \mathbb{R}$ (Here $S$ is the set of symmetric matrices of order n)$

- $F(y,M)=(\delta_{ij}+(p-2)\frac{y_{i}}{|y|}\otimes \frac{y_{j}}{|y|})m_{ij}$ (summation convention adopted)

The  Minimum and Maximum eingenvalues of $\delta_{ij}+(p-2)\frac{y_{i}}{|y|}\otimes \frac{y_{j}}{|y|}$ are respectively $\min(p-1,1)$ and $\max(p-1,1)$. So the $p$-laplacian is uniformly elliptic.

Is the operator $G(\nabla u, D^2u)=|\nabla u|^{\gamma}\Delta_{p}u$, for $\gamma \in (-1,\infty)$, still  uniformly elliptic? If no, why not?